# How can I view and edit PowerPoint presentations that don't render correctly?

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, presentation, microsoft-powerpoint

I have Microsoft PowerPoint projects that I can view correctly on Android, OS X and Windows, but on Linux with LibreOffice Impress, they are not rendered correctly. Instead, the letters and objects are outside the screen.

I need PowerPoint for my job. Is there a fix for that or an alternative app for PowerPoint compatibility without bugs?

Comment: Impress is not Powerpoint. Nobody guaranteed that PP files will be opened correctly. If you need PP use a OS that supports PP and use PP.

Comment: And what you call "bugs" really is not. If you initially create a file in Impress, it will be opened correctly. Microsoft does not disclose the PP file format and it is impossible to fully support it.

Comment: Try WPS office, it supports the pptx file format much better than Libre Office.

Comment: This was never too broad, and even [has a simple fix that has been posted as an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/874095/22949). I've edited this so that it's immediately clear what is being asked, and I recommend we reopen it.

Comment: Use LaTeX+beamer instead of PP.

Comment: omg all this trouble to install wine + office and it failed because wine support only the old office. In the end, WPS office worked !!!!

Comment: @Tim add your answer too. It's the most correct of them all. WPS office has full compatibility with latest office 365

Comment: @Pilot6 OP is clearly coming from Windows and would like a smooth transition. He is asking for a fix or an alternative app. "Impress is not PowerPoint" is neither a fix nor an alternative app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sum it up because there are so many solutions and i like to keep things organised.

After testing every possible solution mentioned here, i add my experience. From 1 to 5; with 1 to be the best solution.

*To have the fonts as mentioned here by San Lin Naing and Nisheet is a must anyway we choose to solve this, except in the option 2.

1. WPS office, mentioned by Tim in the comments. WPS office has the best compatibility with 365 latest office.
2. Virtual Machine plus office 365
3. Wine plus old office, answered from Karol. But we don't have compatibility with latest office 365.
4. Install all possible fonts found in Windows and use the stock LibreOffice. But we don't have compatibility with office 365.
5. Use [the official PowerPoint in the cloud](https://office.live.com/start/PowerPoint.aspx), answered by Ciprian. But a couple of features are missing.

Answer (score 18):

Actually, it may be font issues. Because of Microsoft's fonts are not included in the Linux OS, system substitute with specific fonts.

But these font may not be in same grid size or font attributes.

Try to install Microsoft fonts with following commands in your `terminal`.

```
wget http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
```

Check your documents again. And you should also check fonts such as *Arial*, *Calibri*, etc. in font list.

Comment: yup it was a font issue indeed. thank you , that fixed it. Although now im thinking maybe ill go with karel suggestion to use wine and ms office

Comment: Good to hear that.

Answer (score 18):

If you have a licensed copy of PowerPoint, you can install it in Ubuntu using Wine from the default Ubuntu repositories. Wine is a compatibility layer for running Windows applications on Linux. You will also need to install Installer for Microsoft TrueType core fonts (*ttf-mscorefonts-installer*).

If you don't have a licensed copy of PowerPoint, you can download the free PowerPoint Viewer from the official Microsoft Download Center and use it for viewing PowerPoint presentations or you can upload an incompatible PowerPoint presentation to Google Drive, open it with Google Slides and select *File* -> *Download* -> *ODP Document (.odp)* to convert it to a format that is compatible with Impress and download it to your computer.

Comment: Well, San Lin was right it was the fonts and now its fixed. Although im thinking to go with wine and ms office since Impress isn't too good

Comment: keral , WPS office has full compatibility with the latest office 365. wine only support the old powerpoint. So either we use a virtual machine + office 365 , either WPS office !

Answer (score 7):

Most of the times, this issue pops up due to the standard fonts that come with Windows and are not available in Linux due to license or other issues. As a workaround, I usually create a `.fonts` folder in the home directory (if it doesn't exist) and then copy them there from a Windows fonts library.

Then manually rebuild the font cache:

`fc-cache -f -v`

However, this is a workaround and I will not recommend this for the obvious license issues.

Answer (score 5):

You can use any browser that your machine provides to edit your files in the [official PowerPoint cloud](https://office.live.com/start/PowerPoint.aspx)

While I don't think it has ALL the features of desktop powerpoint, it works better than most desktop alternatives.

Comment: It has very few features but is (almost) guaranteed not to muck up the things that it doesn't support.

Answer (score 0):

I fairly regularly end up showing other people's .pptx files on LibreOffice and with some exceptions I've been quite happy with it (but I'm old enough to remember how bad compatibility was between different versions of poweropint).  The exceptions that I've had most trouble with or know to be significant:

- Fonts have been dealt with already but they're significant.  They're still the ones mos t likely to catch me out, if someone uses something unusual.
- Equation objects (or whatever ms office calls them these days).  This might be the fonts issue again.
- Animations -- but past experience has taught me to avoid them anyway, even if I control the whole platform.
- Transitions, but these usually fail gracefully.
- VBA -- just don't go there.

For the most robust presentations across platforms (and I've been doing this for years now, with sources including powerpoint, impress and latex) just convert everything to pdf.  If you build up/swap elements, that just works out to a new page.  Slide numbering isn't usually helpful anyway so leave it out. But whatever approach you take -- check it in plenty of time.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a font problem, I suggest you look up [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1301497/176654) for installing open source replacements to Microsoft fonts and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884041/libreoffice-calibri-font-availible-when-opening-a-doc-but-not-in-dropdown/1300747#1300747) on how you can install Microsoft fonts using fontist.

(disclaimer: both answers are mine)

Answer (score -2):

Try using [Google Slides](https://www.google.com/slides/about/). It's all in the cloud, handles versioning, revision history, auto-saves, and best of all, it's browser based, so you don't have to install the program everywhere you want to use it.

You can edit, download, and convert Microsoft® Office files in Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides.

To edit an Office file, you can either:

Edit the file using Office Compatibility Mode (OCM)
Convert the file to Google Docs, Sheets, or Slides.
Once you've edited a Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides file, you can then save and export it as an Office file to share with others.

(The above text was copied from [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055139?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en))

Comment: Why the downvotes? The OP specifically mentioned he is looking for a `alternative app for PowerPoint compatibility`. My solution offers exactly this.