# LibreOffice - Calibri font availible when opening a doc but not in dropdown

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

When I open a document sent to me by a colleague Calibri seems to work font as expected with the document:

[image]

But when I create a document on the same computer the Calibri font isn't available in the drop-down.

Comment: Where on the file system is the Calibri font located?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I'm not exactly sure any suggestions on how I can find out?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Possibly you need to install the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package (which includes Calibri). If you do, you'd better install the Debian version in accordance with [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/767826).

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, I'm pretty certain that the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package does NOT include Calibri...

Comment: `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` does not include Calibri, but see my answer below on how to install Calibri using fontist

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The image that you've included with your question shows that the name of the font is in italics. This means that the named font is not installed, and an automatically selected substitute has been used instead. If you hover the cursor over this italicised font name you may see a comment to this effect.

If you don't wish to install the missing font, you can edit the Style to specify a font that *is* installed (right-click within a paragraph, and choose 'Edit Paragraph Style...' from the bottom of the dropdown menu).

In Microsoft Office the same thing happens with missing fonts, but there's usually no indication that a font substitution has occurred.

Answer (score 46):

You have to install it:

1. Install Microsoft's classic TrueType fonts: `sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`
2. Install Microsoft's newer ClearType fonts:

   - which includes: `Constantia, Corbel, Calibri, Cambria, Candara, and Consolas`
   - make *fonts* directory: `mkdir ~/.fonts`
   - > `wget -qO- http://plasmasturm.org/code/vistafonts-installer/vistafonts-installer | bash`
3. Then close and open LibreOffice, if open while you installed these fonts.

Source:

http://www.pcworld.com/article/2863497/how-to-install-microsoft-fonts-in-linux-office-suites.html

Comment: It should be: ```sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer```

Comment: "wget ..." command does not work, unvalid url http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/5/a/f5a3df76-d856-4a61-a6bd-722f52a5be26/PowerPointViewer.exe :-(

Comment: @JiříDoubravský you can grab the required **PowerPointViewer.exe** file (about 60 MB) [here](https://download.cnet.com/PowerPoint-Viewer/3000-2075_4-75450958.html).  You'll then need to make a few very intuitive changes to the script you downloaded earlier...

Comment: if the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package installs successfully but fails to actually download the fonts, install the package from debian sid instead: https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/all/ttf-mscorefonts-installer/download (this is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msttcorefonts/+bug/1767748 )

Comment: Also `cabextract` needs to be installed. You can install it by running `sudo apt install cabextract`.

Comment: since libreoffice now uses snap, you need to make these fonts from `~/.fonts` also available at snap's user home directory. That is, create a symlink as follows: `ln -s ~/.fonts ~/snap/libreoffice/current/.fonts`. See also here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/881667/any-way-to-get-fonts-to-work-in-libreoffice-snap-package

Comment: Looks like [PowerPoint Viewer was retired on April 30, 2018. It's no longer available for download](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-a-presentation-without-powerpoint-2f1077ab-9a4e-41ba-9f75-d55bd9b231a6), at least from its official page. What now?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem a week ago. `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` doesn't include Calibri.

It includes the following fonts:

- Andale Mono
- Arial Black
- Arial (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
- Comic Sans MS (Bold)
- Courier New (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
- Georgia (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
- Impact
- Times New Roman (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
- Trebuchet (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
- Verdana (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
- Webdings

Source: `sudo apt show ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

If you own a legit Microsoft Office license you could copy `calibri.ttf` and all `calibri*.ttf` files (bold, italics, ...) from `C:\Windows\Fonts` and install them on Ubuntu by simply double clicking them. Although I'm not sure if that's according to Office's terms of service.

Comment: How to install this in Mac system?

Answer (score 7):

The fonts *Calibri, Cambria, Candara, Consolas, Constantia* and *Corbel* require a Microsoft Office license, which means that they are only legal on machines where Microsoft Office (available only on Windows and MacOS) is installed.

LibreOffice installs the free font Carlito, which is a replacement for Calibri, and Caladea, which is a replacement for Cambria.

Comment: My system (Lubuntu 16.04) does have LibreOffice installed, but neither of the fonts *Carlito* nor *Caladea* are installed. What system/version are you using?

Comment: In Ubuntu 19.04, you can install them with apt. *Carlito* is in package `fonts-crosextra-carlito` and *Caladea* is in `fonts-crosextra-caladea`.

Comment: these fonts are legal on any system with powerpoint viewer 2007 (regardless of the fact that a linux system may not be able to run it). so it's legal to use them to display files using these fonts on linux in libreoffice & co. However, to create documents with these fonts legally, you must have an appropriate licence to these fonts (for instance office365-licence).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a nice way of installing **Calibri** on your Debian based system.
Run this command in the terminal.

```
$ sudo apt-get install fontforge
```

This will install Font Forge on your system, which will help in font conversion.
After running the above command, execute the command given bellow:

```
$ wget https://gist.github.com/maxwelleite/10774746/raw/ttf-vista-fonts-installer.sh -q -O - | sudo bash
```

This will install the vista font pack on your system that also includes **Calibri**.

Comment: Thank god! Your solution works! Can't beleive I need to install Calibri for ClosedXML to work... smh

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be installing Carlito and Caladea fonts manually, and then manually map them in Tools->Options->Fonts so Calibri and Cambria are always shown as Carlito and Caladea respectively. I think LO 6 does that by default, but in older versions that didn't ship Carlito/Caladea it may be necessary doing it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can install "Calibri" and additional fonts using [fontist](https://github.com/fontist/fontist).

Install Ruby development files:

`sudo apt-get install ruby-dev`

Install fontist:

`sudo gem install fontist`

Update fontist list:

`fontist update`

Install Calibri font:

`fontist install "Calibri"`

Fontist will present you the Microsoft's EULA: please read it and type "yes" followed by enter if you accept it.

Fontist will download the fonts and tell you where the fonts have been installed, in my case it was:
`$HOME/.fontist/fonts/CALIBRI.TTF`

LibreOffice uses [fontconfig](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/) to resolve fonts: fontconfig needs to be aware of the new fonts if you want LibreOffice to use them. Create a local fontconfig configuration file, and add the directory in which the fonts have been installed:

```
mkdir $HOME/.config/fontconfig
mkdir $HOME/.config/fontconfig/conf.d
export CONFFILE=${HOME}/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/10-fontist.conf
echo "<?xml version='1.0'?>" >>  $CONFFILE
echo "<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>" >> $CONFFILE
echo "<fontconfig>" >>  $CONFFILE
echo "<dir>$HOME/.fontist/fonts</dir>" >> $CONFFILE
echo "</fontconfig>" >> $CONFFILE
```

Update fontconfig's cache:

`fc-cache -f`

Check that the font "Calibri" is resolved by fontconfig into the new installed font:

`fc-match "Calibri"`

If everything went right, the output of the previous command should be something like:

`CALIBRI.TTF: "Calibri" "Regular"`

Now LibreOffice will use the newly installed fonts. You can check this is true if LibreOffice does not display the font name in italics anymore.

Comment: If you have already read Microsoft's EULA in the past and you don't need to read it again, use `yes "yes" | fontist install "Calibri"` to accept Microsoft's EULA automatically.