# Firefox stopped showing characters

Tags: 16.04, firefox, fonts

Today I installed the Calibri font in my Ubuntu 16.04 using the method showed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/884053/517513), that is, I crated a `~/.fonts` directory then used this command:

```
wget -qO- http://plasmasturm.org/code/vistafonts-installer/vistafonts-installer | bash
```

do download and install a bundle of fonts.

But instantly after the download finished my Firefox stopped showing some characters. Apparently this happens with some monospaced fonts (not checked).

For example, here in the Stack Exchange network, text formatted as code appears as:

---

[image]

---

(this is a screenshot from the answer I mentioned)

Also, this [cool github page](https://github.com/cereda/arara) appears like this:

---

[image]

---

Furthermore, this question you are reading was written in GEdit then copy-pasted here in the site, because the characters in the message body box do not show at all (although the title box does), like this:

---

[image]

---

What happened whant I ran that script? How to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the `~/.fonts` directory?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I tried, but it didn't do anything. Wait, let me try something... So, after removing the directory from there *and* restarting Firefox (I tried it before, but didn't do the restart) it worked. The problem is that I actually need the Calibri font (stupid standards). Is there a way to make both live in peace?

Comment: One idea: Create the directory `/usr/share/fonts/calibri` and put them there instead of `~/.fonts`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I put them in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/calibri/`, change the permission to `rw-r--r--`, then executed `sudo fc-cache -fvs` to make the system aware of the new fonts. Everything's working now `:)`

Comment: Great! Can you please post that as an answer? (It's fine to answer your own question, and in a couple of days you'll be able to accept it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @GunnarHjalmarsson I solved the problem.

I don't know exactly why that happened, but perhaps Firefox looked for fonts there, found one, and used it. But those fonts don't have a typewriter variant, so *maybe* this is the cause.

### The Solution

@GunnarHjalmarsson suggested to move the fonts to `/usr/share/fonts/calibri`.

Since these were TrueType fonts, I moved them to `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/calibri`

Actually, there are more fonts in the bundle, so I did this:

```bash
for i in calibri cambria candara consola constan corbel; do
    sudo mkdir /usr/share/fonts/truetype/$i # create the folder
    sudo mv ~/.fonts/$i* /usr/share/fonts/truetype/$i/ # move the font files
    sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/$i/* # change permission of the fonts to rw-r--r--
done
```

After that I removed the `~/.fonts` and restarted Firefox and the problem was solved...

But then the fonts were no longer available (for XeTeX, at least). So I downloaded the script which installed the fonts in the first place:

```bash
wget -qO- http://plasmasturm.org/code/vistafonts-installer/vistafonts-installer
```

but didn't execute it. At the end of the script I found `fc-cache -fv ~/.fonts`. Reading the `man fc-cache` page I found out that this command creates sort of a mapping of the available fonts, so I used:

```bash
fc-cache -fvs
```

to regenerate these mappings.

After that I had my Firefox working fine and the fonts were available for XeTeX to use.

---

I must add that on another computer (both with Ubuntu 16.04 and Firefox 58) I did the same procedure described in the question (the font installation), but the problem didn't happen... I have no idea why :P